# Dependent t-test - multiple readings

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

Let's suppose that I'd like to apply dependent t-test to assess if there is a significant difference in the value of the dependent variable between a group of subjects $X_{1}$ and a related group of subjects $X_{2}$.

The same subjects are present in both $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. Now, the twist is that we have multiple readings of the dependent variable for each subject in each group.

Can dependent t-test be applied in this setting? (for instance, by considering the mean of the dependent variable for each subject) Or should I use a different kind of test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rosner's generalization of the paired t-test seems to be the most appropiate statistical test to apply in this specific setting. It assumes a $N_1$ to $N_2$ group matching scheme, in which $N_1$ and $N_2$ may vary between matched sets.

Rosner's original paper contains a detailed description of the method:

> Rosner, B., A generalization of the paired t-test. Journal of the
>   Royal Statistical Society Series C, Applied Statistics. v31. 9-13
>   (1982).

Answer (score 0):

A matched t-test is for comparing two means, where all the subjects are present in both means.

You seem to have multiple means. Therefore, a t-test is not what you want. One generalization of matched t-tests is multilevel models.

Why did you say "related group of subjects"? Are there people in $X_2$ who are not in $X_1$ or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, indeed: some subjects are only in either $X_{1}$ or $X_{2}$. 

By multiple readings, I meant that some subjects may be present more than once in a group, i.e. we are considering several readings of the value of the dependent variable for a single subject in one or both groups.

Comment: Yes, then multilevel models sound good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been reading about multilevel models, but I came across rosner's generalization of the matched t-test; I think that it is just what I was looking for.